# What num_bands parameter do in WebRtcAec_Process() API (Inside WebRtc Echo Module)?

Tags: audio, webrtc, signal-processing, audio-processing, echo-cancellation

I'm working with WebRtc native AEC API.

```
int32_t WebRtcAec_Process(void* aecInst, const float* const* nearend,
                          size_t num_bands, float* const* out,
                          size_t nrOfSamples, int16_t msInSndCardBuf,
                          int32_t skew);
```

I want to cancel echo from audio which has 48K sample rate, single channel(mono) with AEC.

But I don't know why`num_bands` is necessary. If I give value `1` for `num_bands` I got fatal (assertion error) inside AEC (`RTC_DCHECK_EQ(aec->num_bands, num_bands);` fails).

I checked the pre-calculated value of `aec->num_bands` which is `3` for 48K,
From `aec_core.cc`:

```
if (sampFreq == 8000) {
   aec->num_bands = 1;
} else {
   aec->num_bands = (size_t)(sampFreq / 16000);
}
```

Even if I use 3 for `num_bands`, I got invalid-access crash. Do I need to split every frame into 3 part in some way?

Answer (score 0):

How many samples are you trying to process? I seem to remember it only supports 80 or 160.

Also, I wrote a Java wrapper for the webRTC echo cancellation module a long time ago. I seem to think there were two separate implementations of the AEC module, one for mobile and one for desktop.

The one I used was the mobile one and only supported 8Khz and 16Khz.